# Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

When I run the script using web API automation rest assured framework,

I am not getting the proper api response and below are the error are posted.

```
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:542)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2055)
at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:350)
at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$post$2.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1181)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter.filter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:140)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1655)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1661)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1029)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:816)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:203)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:175)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at webapi.FlightSearch.main(FlightSearch.java:42)
```

Please provide some inputs so that socket exceptions are resolved.

```java
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);

serverSocket.setSoTimeout(120000);

RestAssured.baseURI= "https://192.168.126.157:95";
String response=given().log().all()
    .header("Authorization-Basic:","0b017b0c0d414e20ee0d2e4adbed686d7c297a6d2f8ec8f9eddc2016d9513482a086fe8712ef0530")
    .header("Content-Type","application/json")  
    .config(RestAssuredConfig.config()              
    .httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()         
    .setParam("http.connection.timeout", 1000)))    
    .body(payload.FlightSearchpayload()).when().post("/Affiliate/Flight/Aw_SearchFlight")
    .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).body("sessionID", equalTo("AW-J0LIPOEG72QY"))  
    .header("server", "192.168.126.157:95")
    .extract().response().asString();
        
    System.out.println(response);
        
    JsonPath js=ReUsableMethods.rawToJson(response);
    String id=js.get("ID");
    System.out.println(id);
```